Elasticsearch saving date without a year 02/29 problem
I've defined in elasticsearch a field of type date in the format "MM-dd" which works fine except for the date 02-29.
I understand that elastic does use a year when saving (even though it doesn't seem to affect the field) and the year elastic is using probably didn't have the 29th in Feb.
I've tried saving the full year and letting elastic do the parse but elastic requires me to send the date in the same format.
any ideas of how I can save this value?
Thanks!

You should customize a date parser by update_by_query. Initially your date stores as keyword, and then the date is parsed in update_by_query
Sample documents
PUT /date_without_year/_bulk?refresh
{"create":{"_id":1}}
{"source_date":"01-01"}
{"create":{"_id":2}}
{"source_date":"12-01"}
{"create":{"_id":3}}
{"source_date":"02-29"}
{"create":{"_id":4}}
{"source_date":"02-01"}

update_by_query with the custom date parser and the any_leap_year parameter
POST /date_without_year/_update_by_query
{
    "script": {
        "source": """
            int leapYear = params["any_leap_year"];
            String sourceDate = ctx["_source"]["source_date"];
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd");
            MonthDay monthDay = MonthDay.parse(sourceDate, dtf);
            ctx["_source"]["date"] = monthDay.atYear(leapYear);
        """,
        "params": {
            "any_leap_year": 2024
        }
    }
}

Query to get documents with the parsed date
GET /date_without_year/_search?filter_path=hits.hits.fields
{
    "fields": [
        "date",
        "source_date"
    ]
}

Response
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "source_date" : [
                        "01-01"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "2024-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "source_date" : [
                        "12-01"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "2024-02-29T00:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "source_date" : [
                        "02-29"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "fields" : {
                    "date" : [
                        "2024-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                    ],
                    "source_date" : [
                        "02-01"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

